# Photoshop cs5 - Subpixel sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixels, photoshop-cs5

Is there a way I can disable subpixel work for a specific document?
I'd like to be able to move an element on a full pixel grid instead of subpixels, preventing stuff to be placed at 128,23 Y-axis for example.

Same applies to sizes, can I make it so it can only have full pixels for width and height?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you can not work with anything less than a full pixel in Photoshop if you are talking about the axis settings those get rounded up or down and the object is shifted accordingly. If your object has feathering this will be affected by the .23 but it will still use a full pixel not a partial one.

I don't know where you would be seeing partial pixel sizes for the document size though...

[image: PixelSnap]

The top is with no pixel snap setting and the bottom is with a pixel snap setting. Without it the partial pixel gets feathered.

Comment: I think he must be referring to moving vector objects or paths.

Comment: @paradroid That's what I meant. Not the document size, but rather the position of a vector object in it.

Comment: It is the same for vector images it creates a feather in the neighboring pixel if you use a partial pixel the color varies based on how much it is set to. You can set the vector shapes to Snap to Pixels under the menu next to them on the vector shapes toolbar. This will help but you could still manually set it to feather.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could create a 1px grid and enable the snap to grid feature, will more or less fix my problem. Note that if the object you are resizing or moving is already in a subpixel size it will stay that way.

And sometimes when you move it, it will snap to a .99 instead a .00
Anyway, good enough for me.